# Master PDF Editor v1.9

Tags: pdf

I recently downloaded and installed "Master PDF Editor" on my laptop. I edited a PDF file attaching "Sticky Notes" and emailed it as an attachment to one of my contacts who is seeing the "Sticky Notes" icons but cannot open them!  I then opened the emailed attachment on my desktop and sure enough the attachment opened. I'm seeing the icons but I cannot open them also!

I tried installing the app "Master PDF Editor" from Ubuntu Software Center but it would not install. Ubuntu 12.04 is the OS on both my laptop and desktop!

Can anyone help?  Please note that I am a stranger to terminal use!!

Answer (score 1):

Since answering this question, I have come to understand that there is a distinct difference between pdf editing and pdf annotation.  Proper annotation is done using a non-intrusive/non-destructive pdf annotation markup language that can be changed, rearranged & cleaned-up/deleted.  So while xournal and inkscape allow "annotation", it is not in this language and it is not necessarily non-destructive.  Meaning, those using other software may not be able to read it, or can only read the part that ended up permanently changing the document.  The only proper annotation software available on linux, that is software using the pdf annotation markup, is the DocuTrak software (below) running under wine.  (As of 2015.)

As answered previously:

I can't help you with Master PDF Editor, but I have used DocuTrak's PDF Xchange Viewer, which allows document annotation.  It's free (as in beer) and it seems they now also have an "Xchange Editor" (which I have not explored - perhaps they've just split out the editing functions?):
http://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads

It's a Windows product, but the Viewer, at least, is a stand-alone exe and runs under wine (the MS Win Compatibility Layer).  You can find reports on wine software compatibility at winehq.org.  See, eg.:
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5549

Just install the package "wine" and then follow instructions from there.  I remember it as being quite straightforward.

The only other software I've tried for pdf editing (not just annotation) on ubuntu is the pdfedit package, but that's real alpha software.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "hand tool" under the tools bar

Comment: Can you please explain how?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)